# Cannot Find Global Action

Tags: global-actions

There is a global action called New Case on my Account record/ page layouts. When I test that action, it allows me select a record type. Our users have asked that button be customized to pre-populate the account name. For instance, if I select "new case" on the "Test" account, the newly created case will already have "Test" in the Account Name field. The system does not allow us to create a custom New Case global action without selecting a record type. This isn't feasible for our org, as we have quite a few record types. Other than a using a flow, is there a way to create a New Case global action for lightning where the Account name field is pre-populated and the record type is dynamic (based on user selection)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are using different record type for an object and want to use actions, you must relate it to a record type to make it visible on the page layout.

For example, The Case object is having  4 record type and users need to choose any of them, then creating 4 different actions for the same purpose is not advisable.

What I suggest is use Case related list on the page layout in lightning. It will fill your both the criteria:-

1. It will allow your users to select the record type before creating the record
2. It will have the account field pre-field by current account

If you are having case related list on cLassic, it will not come automatically, You need to add it by the following steps:-

1. Go to the account record and click edit page in the dropdown of setup icon
2. Drag the related list-single component and select case
3. save it and activate it

Another option is to create a custom URL button which will have URL as:-

> URLFOR($Action.Case.New)

You can pass the account id but it may happen that it will not work in Lightning. SO first criteria will be fulfilled via this but filling the second one is not sure.